# How to insert the first line of a csv file in a php database?

Tags: php, sql-server, fgetcsv

I have two csv files like, first csv file BI1_2020.csv like this:

```
391;FR-RC O/O HOSSEGOR MEN;07/21/2020;0021000002509;GR01-S8;8666-CLEAR;TU;1;15;12.5;0;EUR
391;EN-RC O/O HOSSEGOR MEN;07/21/2020;0021000002510;WLY9BO-RC;1000-WHITE;2;1;22.99;19.16;4.81;EUR
391;FR-RC O/O HOSSEGOR MEN;07/21/2020;0021000002510;WLY5DB-RC;40-RED;8;1;19.99;16.66;4.2;EUR
391;EN-RC O/O HOSSEGOR MEN;07/21/2020;0021000002510;OBOAU4-RC;90-BLACK;2;1;39.99;33.33;11.27;EUR
391;FR-RC O/O HOSSEGOR MEN;07/21/2020;0021000002515;4OCEAN-HF;40-RED;TU;1;20;16.67;0;EUR
```

and another BI2_2020.csv like this:

```
27336;00203-ET1;90-BLACK;9.5;2
27336;00203-ET1;90-BLACK;10;1
27336;00203-ET1;90-BLACK;12;1
27396;00203-ET1;90-BLACK;9.5;3
...
```

I wrote a code that depending on the filename, either BI1 or BI2 will fill with data from the csv file of the tables in my database. The code works well but for both files it doesn't insert the first line of the csv file. How do I fix this?

```
<?php
// Starting clock time in seconds 
$time_start = microtime(true); 

include("../connexion.php");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 54000);
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$dir   = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/test/';
$allFiles = scandir($dir);
$dest = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/test/files/';

foreach($allFiles as $file) {

    if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
    { 
        $file = $dir.$file;
        $filename = basename( $file );
        
        if ( strpos( $filename, 'BI1_' ) === 0 ) {
            if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
            
                //To remove BOM in the fist cell
                fseek($handle, 3);
            
                $bi1_values =  array();
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {
                    if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
                        continue;
                    }
 
                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s A', $data[2]);
                    // if ($date === false) {
                        // break;
                    // }

                    $date1 = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2020-07-07
                    $date2 = $date->format('Hi A'); // 1247 AM
            
                    $bi1_values[] = "('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$date1','$date2','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";                 
                    if (count($bi1_values) == 1000) { 
                        $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Sales (storenumber, storename, date, time, TransRef, stylecode, color, size, quantity, unit_price, SalesExGST, cost, currency) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi1_values);
                        $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        if (!$stmt) {                           
                            $file1 = fopen("errors/erreur_BI1.txt", "w");
                            fwrite($file1,$query);
                            fclose($file1);
                            // $file1 = "errors/erreur_BI1.txt";                      
                            // file_put_contents($file1, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                            // echo $conn->error; }
                        }
                        $bi1_values = array();
                    }   
                }
                if (!empty($bi1_values)) { 
                    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Sales (storenumber, storename, date, time, TransRef, stylecode, color, size, quantity, unit_price, SalesExGST, cost, currency) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi1_values);
                    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                    if (!$stmt) { 
                            $file1 = fopen("errors/erreur_BI1.txt", "w");
                            fwrite($file1,$query);
                            fclose($file1);
                        // $file1 = "errors/erreur_BI1.txt";                      
                        // file_put_contents($file1, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                        // echo $conn->error; }
                    }
                }   
                        
                fclose($handle);
                
                //Moving the file to another folder             
                if(!rename($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                    echo "error copy";
                }
            }
                    
        } elseif ( strpos( $filename, 'BI2_' ) === 0 ) {
    
            if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
                  
                // To remove BOM in the fist cell
                fseek($handle, 3);
            
                $bi2_values =  array();
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {        
                    // print_r($data);
                    if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $bi2_values[] = "('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]', '$timestamp')";                 
                    if (count($bi2_values) == 1000) { 
                        $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Inventory (storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, timestamp) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi2_values);
                        $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        
                        if (!$stmt) { 
                                $file2 = fopen("errors/erreur_BI2.txt", "w");
                                fwrite($file2,$query);
                                fclose($file2);
                            // $file2 = "errors/erreur_BI2.txt";                      
                            // file_put_contents($file2, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                            // echo $conn->error;}
                        }   
                        $bi2_values = array();
                    } 
                }
                if (!empty($bi2_values)) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Inventory (storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, timestamp) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi2_values);
                    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        
                    if (!$stmt) { 
                                $file2 = fopen("errors/erreur_BI2.txt", "w");
                                fwrite($file2,$query);
                                fclose($file2);
                        // $file2 = "errors/erreur_BI2.txt";                      
                        // file_put_contents($file2, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                        // echo $conn->error;}

                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);

                // Moving the file to another folder             
                if(!rename($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                    echo "error copy";
                } 
                    
            }

        }   elseif ( strpos( $filename, 'BI3_' ) === 0 ) {
    
            if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
                  
                // To remove BOM in the fist cell
                fseek($handle, 3);
            
                $bi3_values =  array();
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {        
                    // print_r($data);
                    if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $bi3_values[] = "('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]', '$data[5]')";                 
                    if (count($bi3_values) == 1000) { 
                        $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Style (stylecode, brandname, department, category, description, season) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi3_values);
                        $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        
                        if (!$stmt) { 
                                $file3 = fopen("errors/erreur_BI3.txt", "w");
                                fwrite($file3,$query);
                                fclose($file3);
                            // $file3 = "errors/erreur_BI3.txt";                      
                            // file_put_contents($file3, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                            // echo $conn->error;}
                        }   
                        $bi3_values = array();
                    } 
                }
                if (!empty($bi3_values)) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Style (stylecode, brandname, department, category, description, season) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi3_values);
                    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        
                    if (!$stmt) { 
                                $file3 = fopen("errors/erreur_BI3.txt", "w");
                                fwrite($file3,$query);
                                fclose($file3);
                                // $file3 = "errors/erreur_BI3.txt";                      
                                // file_put_contents($file3, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                                // echo $conn->error;}

                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);

                // Moving the file to another folder             
                if(!rename($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                    echo "error copy";
                } 
                    
            }

        }
    }
}
$texte = "Process took ". number_format(microtime(true) - $time_start, 2). " seconds.";

file_put_contents("time.txt", $texte);
  
echo "good !";


?>
```

Comment: There is `break` statement when `$date` equals `false`. Could that be causing it? And shouldn't it be `continue`?

Comment: In my first line my date is the same as the others so he should insert the line but each time he skips it @Rolf

Comment: Check if the file begins with BOM, that might be causing problems reading the first line.

Comment: Add error checking for your queries.

Comment: Print a message before each `continue`, to see if that is being triggered.

Comment: My csv files are indeed encoded in UTF-8-BOM @Barmar

Comment: I guess the `rewind($handle);` is intended to deal with this, but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: I had put it because in the BI2_ it added me the first line but with a ? in the first cell @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure how `rewind()` would fix that. You should use `fseek()` to skip over the BOM.

Comment: Do you think I could improve the speed of insertion into the tables? Or do them at the same time? @Barmar

Comment: You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load into a table directly from the file, instead of using the script.

Comment: But I still have to use my PHP to make the choice of the filename @Barmar

Comment: `$conn->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$dir$file' ...")`

Comment: It doesn't work with the addition of my variable for the time $timestamp @Barmar

Comment: You can put `SET timestamp = '$timestamp'` in the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query.

Comment: I've tried this but no sucess.. $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE dbo.Y2_Inventory FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' SET timestamp = '$timestamp (storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, timestamp)"; @Barmar

Comment: Maybe it's because my table is in a SQL Server database? @Barmar

Comment: I assumed we were talking about MySQL. I don't know SQL-Server.

Comment: And multiple insertion you think is a good solution? I was told that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057309/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-insertion-of-the-csv-data-in-a-database-in-php/63057820?noredirect=1#comment111509895_63057820 @Barmar

Comment: Yes, I recommend that if you can't load directly from the file, I've used it in some of my applications, for instance when copying data between servers. BTW, the person who answered your other question also assumed MySQL. You should use the sql-server tag so people know.

Comment: And if I want to add in a .txt file the lines that are not inserted in my database, is my code good with what I added? @Barmar

Comment: you need to open the file in append mode, otherwise each line is going to replace the previous contents rather than adding to it. Also, what is `$stmt` in `if (!$stmt)`? You got rid of the code that uses that to save to the DB.

Comment: I updated my code, to open the file you think with file_put_contents ? @Barmar

Comment: I generally recommend it, it simplifies the code. Remember to use the `FILE_APPEND` option.

Comment: Like I just changed now? @Barmar

Comment: You're missing the string to put into the file.

Comment: I changed my code with everything you told me yesterday, I have no error but nothing fits in my tables... And the error file create itself well but in it there is marked at each line "INSERT INTO .... VALUES" @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking `count($bi1_values)` before you add anything to it. So the count will always be 0, and you won't add to it. You should be adding the row of values to the array unconditionally, then using the count to determine whether to execute the query to insert all those rows.

You also have `fclose($handle);` inside the loop, which will prevent reading the rest of the file. It should be after the loop is done.

```
<?php
// Starting clock time in seconds 
$time_start = microtime(true); 

include("../connexion.php");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 54000);
// $timestamp= date("y-m-d H:i");
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$dir   = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/test/';
$allFiles = scandir($dir);
$dest = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/retail_BI/test/files/';

foreach($allFiles as $file) {

    if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
    { 
        $file = $dir.$file;
        $filename = basename( $file );
        
        if ( strpos( $filename, 'BI1_' ) === 0 ) {
            if (($handle = fopen("$filename", "r")) !== false) {
            
                //To remove BOM in the fist cell
                fseek($handle, 3);
            
                $bi1_values =  array();
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {
                    if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
                        continue;
                    }
 
                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s A', $data[2]);
                    if ($date === false) {
                        break;
                    }

                    $date1 = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2020-07-07
                    $date2 = $date->format('Hi A'); // 1247 AM
            
                    $bi1_values[] = "('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$date1','$date2','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";                 
                    if (count($bi1_values) == 1000) { 
                        $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Sales (storenumber, storename, date, time, TransRef, stylecode, color, size, quantity, unit_price, SalesExGST, cost, currency) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi1_values);
                        $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        if (!$stmt) { 
                            $file1 = "erreur_BI1.txt";                      
                            file_put_contents($file1, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                            // echo $conn->error; }
                        }
                        $bi1_values = array();
                    }   
                }
                if (!empty($bi1_values)) { 
                    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Sales (storenumber, storename, date, time, TransRef, stylecode, color, size, quantity, unit_price, SalesExGST, cost, currency) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi1_values);
                    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                    if (!$stmt) { 
                        $file1 = "erreur_BI1.txt";                      
                        file_put_contents($file1, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                        // echo $conn->error; }
                    }
                }   
                        
                fclose($handle);
                
                //Moving the file to another folder             
                if(!rename($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                    echo "error copy";
                }
            }
                    
        } else if ( strpos( $filename, 'BI2_' ) === 0 ) {
    
            if (($handle = fopen("$filename", "r")) !== false) {
                  
                // To remove BOM in the fist cell
                fseek($handle, 3);
            
                $bi2_values =  array();
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== false) {        
                    // print_r($data);
                    if (empty(array_filter($data))) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $bi2_values[] = "('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]', '$timestamp')";                 
                    if (count($bi2_values) == 1000) { 
                        $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Inventory (storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, timestamp) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi2_values);
                        $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        
                        if (!$stmt) { 
                            $file2 = "erreur_BI2.txt";                      
                            file_put_contents($file2, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                            // echo $conn->error;}
                        }   
                        $bi2_values = array();
                    } 
                }
                if (!empty($bi2_values)) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Y2_Inventory (storenumber, stylecode, colour, size, units, timestamp) VALUES " . implode(',', $bi2_values);
                    $stmt = $conn->query( $query );
                        
                    if (!$stmt) { 
                        $file2 = "erreur_BI2.txt";                      
                        file_put_contents($file2, $query . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                        // echo $conn->error;}

                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);

                // Moving the file to another folder             
                if(!rename($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                    echo "error copy";
                } 
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
$texte = "Process took ". number_format(microtime(true) - $time_start, 2). " seconds.";

file_put_contents("time.txt", $texte, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
  
echo "good !";


?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works perfectly! There's just an extra brace at the end to close the first "if (strpos..."  @Barmar

Comment: I changed 'file_put_contents' with 'fopen' because at each execution of the script it doesn't overwrite the old errors but puts the new one after it @Barmar

Comment: The insertion is weird: on the second file no problem, but on the 3rd it doesn't insert any data and the 2nd it stops at 4000 lines. I think that if it finds a line in error in the 1000 lines block it doesn't insert the whole block instead of just excluding the line in question. Because if I do a classic line-by-line insertion it works fine @Barmar

Comment: `FILE_APPEND` should make it append instead of overwrite.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL-Server. MySQL has a setting called `max_allowed_packet`, which limits the size of a single query, there may be something analogous in SQL-Server.

Comment: Certainly the whole block is executed as a single query. It either succeeds or fails as a whole. That's why this is faster than executing a separate query for each row. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218905/discussion-between-eric27-and-barmar).