# Cakephp 3 - Import Large CSV to DB using file upload Error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I will be putting everything in bullets to not make the question lengthy..

- I have 800,000++ rows of CSV
- Uploads it thru cakephp 3 `$this->Form->upload()` **WORKING**
- Save the file in webroot for now **WORKING**
- Open the file using `box/spout` **WORKING**
- Loop thru each row and save each row to the database **PARTIALLY WORKING**

So everything seems to be working fine except after about 5 mins and ~200,000 records saved in the database it returns an error 503 service unavailable. **I am able to save 800,000 rows on my localhost**, but **this error appears on the live site which is hosted on GoDaddy**.

Are there any settings I can change to prevent this error from happening? Maybe increase a timeout for this specific error? (I have `set_time_limit(0)` and `ini_set('memory_limit','-1')` just to make it work. I have even set `max_execution_time` to a bigger number in the servers `php.ini`.

Not really sure what solution I can do to fix this. Any suggestion would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Try using an optimized approach for inserting the entries into the database. Use batch insertion instead if you're inserting one by one(for better time efficiency), and you can optimize the memory by reading and processing the data in chunks. This would definitely reduce the load on the server.    <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057309/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-insertion-of-the-csv-data-in-a-database-in-php/63057820#63057820>

Comment: This is helpful. I will test it and will let you know! :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time job, then you can split the CSV data in multiple CSV. Like you can set 100,000 rows per CSV and following this you need to upload 8 to 10 CSV to save all record in live Database.

If it is dynamic from user end, you don't know how much rows that CSV will contain, you should limit the number of rows.

Or you can save the CSV file in the server (maybe in webroot) and tell user to wait and can save CSV records to Database through Cake Shell. Cake shell does not run in HTTP protocol, you don't have any execution time limit if you use set_time_limit(0) and ini_set('memory_limit','-1')

Cake shell is same like we write code in controller and model.
Details: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/shells.html

We use cake shell for larger task like creating reports for 200000 users in one shot.