# Best Method For Quick Uploading of MYSQL Data with Normalization?

Tags: mysql

Here is my situation. I got this imaginary raw csv data set like this and would contain about 1M lines on average. I would get this data set often every 2 weeks.

```
PROJECT, MD5SUM_VALUE, USAGE_NAME
A,132412341324asdf,Apple
B,13404892340asdf9,Banana
...
```

I got mysql tables for

```
PROJECT_TABLE (id, value),
MD5SUM_VALUE (id, value)
USAGE_NAME (id, name)
RECORD_TABLE (id, project_id, MD5SUM_id, USAGE_id)
```

I have been using scripts to quickly file load the values of PROJECT (using INSERT IGNORE) into PROJECT_TABLE and a similar strategy to do this for MD5SUM_VALUE and USAGE_NAME.

As it stands today, I got about

- 17,115,235 unique row entries for USAGE_NAME table
- 3,001,675  unique row entries for MD5SUM_VALUE table
- 200 unique row entries for PROJECT table
- 59m+ rows for RECORD_TABLE table

My uploading of the RECORD_TABLE seems slow. I need to do a query to identify the ids (project_id, MD5SUM_id, USAGE_id) and do this 1 million times+ per raw csv file.

Is there a better way to upload the data? Seems like no way to upload this data part quickly? Should I structure differently?

Comment: Can you use `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: I already do this for populating the USAGE_NAME, MD5SUM_VALUE, PROJECT tables. How can you do this for the RECORD_TABLE?

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible without a script, since it has to find the IDs.

Comment: The usual way to optimize that is to do `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), (...), ...`. Collect hundreds of rows into a single query.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057309/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-insertion-of-the-csv-data-in-a-database-in-php/63057820?noredirect=1#comment111509895_63057820

Comment: @Barmar it is possible without a script; see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary table and use that to generate/lookup ids and then insert into your record_table.  Assuming you have autoincrement ids on project_table, md5sum_table, and usage_name, and unique keys on the non-id columns:

```
create temporary table record_table_load (
    project varchar(255),
    project_id int,
    md5sum_value varchar(32),
    md5sum_id int,
    usage_name varchar(255),
    usage_id int
);
load data local infile 'foo.csv'
into table record_table_load
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
(project, md5sum_value, usage_name);
insert ignore into project_table (value) select distinct project from record_table_load;
insert ignore into md5sum_table (value) select distinct md5sum_value from record_table_load;
insert ignore into usage_name (name) select distinct usage_name from record_table_load;
update record_table_load join project_table on project_table.value=record_table_load.project set record_table_load.project_id=project_table.id;
update record_table_load join md5sum_table on md5sum_table.value=record_table_load.md5sum_value set record_table_load.md5sum_id=md5sum_table.id;
update record_table_load join usage_name on usage_name.name=record_table_load.usage_name set record_table_load.usage_id=usage_name.id;
insert into record_table (project_id, md5sum_id, usage_id) select project_id, md5sum_id, usage_id from record_table_load;
drop temporary table record_table_load;
```

If you want to avoid using `insert ignore` or you don't have unique constraints on those values, do the lookup, then insert of any values not found, then another lookup.

Comment: @Gordon did this answer help you?  have you tried it out?